# What is the better way to get LiveData object after Transformation?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm currently taking a [Developing Android Apps with Kotlin](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012) course, and there's a task to move LiveData object — a Long type from CountDownTimer — from observer to xml file. But it has to be transformed from Long to String.

So the code that was given is:

```
private val _time = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val time: LiveData<Long>
    get() = _time

val timeString = Transformations.map(time) { time ->
    DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(time)
}
```

But wouldn't it be better to use getter instead:

```
private val _time = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val time: LiveData<String>
    get() = Transformations.map(_time) { time ->
        DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(time)
    }
```

Is there a reason not to use getter, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the first solution is to keep the `time` variable intact, as you might want to use it for something else later on. For example, apart from just printing the time, maybe you'd also want to do some kind of a calculation with it - in which case, it is better to keep it as-is.

As a general rule, you don't want to directly modify the data you need to print or show in the UI - it's better to do the transformation directly when showing it (if showing it just in one place in the code), or create a separate UI variable which does the transformation.

Comment: I was trying to make it look consistent, so I didn't even think about this, thank you

Comment: If the answer is what you were looking for, please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the arrows) :)